# Setting driver group / icon

Tags: windows, driver, inf

I'm writing a Windows driver. So far everything looks OK and the driver installs / works as desired. I can't figure out how to set driver group to one of the existing groups and icon-sets.

By driver group I mean the group that you see in Device Manager (Monitors, Network Adapters, Processors, Ports (COM & LPT), etc.)

Even if I write the same name, Device manager will create a new group:

```
[Strings]
ClassName="Keyboards"
```

Also, I found no way of setting the icon for my device. I tried setting Class to Keyboard, HIDClass, System, whatever, but the icon shown is always that of Network adapters.

```
[Version]
Class=SCSIAdapter   ;System
```

How can I properly set the desired group and icon?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a year old, but figured I would drop my thoughts for the benefit of future needs.

To achieve what you are trying to do, you need to specify both a Class and a ClassGuid for an inbox class within the Version section.

```
[Version]
Class=System
ClassGuid={4D36E97D-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}
```

Note that you can not change name or the icon for inbox classes.

For the device icon you can easily set it using AddProperty directive within a DDInstall section. [MSDN AddProperty Directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/hardware/drivers/install/inf-addproperty-directive)

The following is a quote from a post over on osronline.com from Doron Holan from Microsoft:

> download.microsoft.com/download/a/f/7/af7777e5-7dcd-4800-8a0a-b18336565f5b/CustomIcon.doc
>
> Abstract
>   { This paper summarizes the steps device vendors take to customize device icons in My Computer, Autoplay, Device Manager, and New Hardware dialogs in the Microsoft Windows family of operating systems.
>
> Specifying a per driver package icon
>
> technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/ff543520(v3Dvs.100).aspx
>
> The DEVPKEY_DrvPkg_Icon device property represents a list of device icons that Windows uses to visually represent a device instance.